# Why $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ 2}, \sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]$ is less than or equal to $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

During class, when talking about field extension, my professor said it is easy to see  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ 2}, \sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]$ is less than or equal to $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}]$. However, I just don't understand why $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ 2}, \sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]$ is less than or equal to $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}]$? Why I am able to compare the degrees of these two extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{5}$ is a zero of $x^2-5 \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})[x]$, so $$[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})]=[ [\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})](\sqrt{5}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})] \leq 2=[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5}):\Bbb Q]$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! I wonder if I can prove ^2−5 is irreducible over ℚ(√2), can I then say [ℚ(√2, √5) : ℚ(√2)] = 2?

Comment: Yes! Since its degree cannot be one, otherwise $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, which is false